# Update 2 fields onValueChange?

Tags: google-app-maker

I have a dropdown @status with a "Done" and "Pending" options. When one of those options is selected I would also like to update a different field called @type with the value "Set".

Could I do this under @status drop-down with some custom action onValueChange or is there a better way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do it on the **onValueChange** event handler, although I would recommend to do it instead on the **onValueEdit** event handler, unless you are planning to programatically change the value of the dropdown, then you better stick with the **onValueChange**. Here is what you need to do:

```
widget.datasource.item.type = "Set";
```

Reference: https://developers.google.com/appmaker/scripting/api/client#Record